# Scala: type classes, default and custom implicit conversions in the same scope

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, typeclass

I'm wondering whether there is an elegant way to have both the default implicit conversions and some user-defined custom conversion in the same scope. I have the following use-case:

1. Suppose we have a trait which defines some binary operation (e.g.  `PlusSupport`, which defines `plus(x, y)`) for generic type `E`
2. We can add `"+"` syntax on objects that can be converted to `PlusSupport` and for that we need to provide implicit conversions
3. There are a lot of default implicit conversions to `PlusSupport` for many different types and user of our library *always* import them as e.g. `import defaultConversions._` (import all and don't think a lot )
4. Now the user adds some custom implicit conversion (`implicit val customConversion = ...`) for some type which already has the default conversion from `import defaultConversions._` (this custom conversion may be either user-written or provided by the third-party library `com.3dparty.veryAdvancedConversions.AwesomePlus`); the user expects that his custom conversion will be used

Here is the code example:

```
trait A // some type A
trait B // some type B
// ... many other types goes here

// some binary operation
trait PlusSupport[E] {
  def plus(a: E, b: E): E
}

object defaultConversions {
  // default conversion of A to PlusSupport[A]
  implicit def mkPlusSupportForA: A => PlusSupport[A] = _ => (a1: A, a2: A) => a1

  // default conversion of B to PlusSupport[B]
  implicit def mkPlusSupportForB: B => PlusSupport[B] = _ => (b1: B, b2: B) => b1

  // ... many other conversions goes here
}

// + operator for elements with PlusSupport 
class PlusOps[E](lhs: E)(plus: PlusSupport[E]) {
  def +(rhs: E): E = plus.plus(lhs, rhs)
}

// adds "+" syntax
trait PlusSyntax {
  implicit def plusOps[E](lhs: E)(implicit mkPlusSupport: E => PlusSupport[E]): PlusOps[E]
  = new PlusOps[E](lhs)(mkPlusSupport(lhs))
}

object syntax extends PlusSyntax


def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  // import all default conversions for A, B, C, D etc. etc.
  import defaultConversions._
  import syntax._

  // setup my custom conversion for A
  implicit val myCustomPlusForA: A => PlusSupport[A] = _ => (a1: A, a2: A) => a2

  val a1: A = new A {}
  val a2: A = new A {}
  val b1: B = new B {}
  val b2: B = new B {}

  // myCustomPlusForA should be used
  println((a1 + a2) == a1)
  println((a1 + a2) == a2)

  // default conversion for B should be used
  println((b1 + b2) == b1)
  println((b1 + b2) == b2)

}
```

It doesn't compile with the following error:

```
Error:(52, 19) type mismatch;
found   : A
required: String
   println((a1 + a2) == a1)
```

The code can be corrected in 2 ways:

1. We can remove `implicit val myCustomPlusForA` -- everything will work fine and the *default implicit conversion from `defaultConversions` will be used* ; but we need to use exactly my custom conversion, so this is not an option
2. We can change `import defaultConversions._` to `import  defaultConversions.{everything except conversion for A}` and then `myCustomPlusForA` will be used ; but this is also a bad option since the user of the library would not take care about it (the user just want to import all "defaults" and add some "customization", e.g. he can use `implicit val myCustomPlusForA` without `implicit` keyword (all compiles fine) and than  to add `implicit` just to test how things are changed with full customization)

So the question is how to fix the code so that both `import defaultConversions._` and `implicit val myCustomPlusForA` will be in the same scope and exactly `myCustomPlusForA` will be used by the compiler? Which code pattern should be used to achieved the desired behaviour?

**Update:** the workaround that I have found so far is to [use default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717868/test-if-implicit-conversion-is-available) for implicit parameter and completely remove `import defaultConversions._` (even make `defaultConversions` private to avoid its usage by the users):

```
private def defaultMk[E](ev: E): E => PlusSupport[E] = ev match {
  case _: A => mkPlusSupportForA.asInstanceOf[E => PlusSupport[E]]
  case _: B => mkPlusSupportForB.asInstanceOf[E => PlusSupport[E]]
  case _ => ???
}

trait PlusSyntax {
  implicit def plusOps[E](lhs: E)(implicit mkPlusSupport: E => PlusSupport[E]
    = defaultConversions.defaultMk(lhs)): PlusOps[E] = new PlusOps[E](lhs)(mkPlusSupport(lhs))
}
```

but it really looks strange to do the check at runtime while all information is available at the compile time and the compiler should just "substitute" the correct conversion.

Comment: Have you tried implicit prioritization, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886953/is-there-a-way-to-control-which-implicit-conversion-will-be-the-default-used)?

Comment: I have seen that question when was thinking about the solution, but I did not figure out how I can adapt implicit prioritization to solve my problem

Comment: implicit conversions are generally evil

Comment: @JesperNordenberg you were right -- just played with prioritization and solved the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @JesperNordenberg suggested in comment, one can use implicit prioritization. So, in order to make things work one just need to move methods from `defaultConversions` to a companion object of `PlusSupport` and delete `defaultConversions` at all:

```
trait PlusSupport[E] {
  def plus(a: E, b: E): E
}

// place default implicit conversions into companion object
private object PlusSupport {
  // default conversion of A to PlusSupport[A]
  implicit def mkPlusSupportForA: A => PlusSupport[A] = _ => (a1: A, a2: A) => a1

  // default conversion of B to PlusSupport[B]
  implicit def mkPlusSupportForB: B => PlusSupport[B] = _ => (b1: B, b2: B) => b1

  // ... many other conversions goes here
}


def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  // no need to import from object PlusSupport

  import syntax._

  // setup my custom conversion for A
  implicit val myCustomPlusForA: A => PlusSupport[A] = _ => (a1: A, a2: A) => a2

  val a1: A = new A {}
  val a2: A = new A {}
  val b1: B = new B {}
  val b2: B = new B {}

  // myCustomPlusForA will be used
  println((a1 + a2) == a1)
  println((a1 + a2) == a2)

  // default conversion for B will be used
  println((b1 + b2) == b1)
  println((b1 + b2) == b2)

}
```